# Home IP Address Management?

Tags: ip-address, static-ip

Are there any better, free solutions to managing static IPs at home than a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with DHCP static leases, but keep all the configuration information in an Excel file so I can reference it more easily than logging into the router.

Answer (score 16):

DHCP static leases are much better.  They're easily managed, many consumer grade and SOHO routers have the ability to do so, and it enables everything to be done under one single management tool.

Comment: Indeed, if you have a DSL and/or wireless router already in your home network, you may well find that it's got a DHCP server built in that will allow you specify a range of IPs and to always assign a specific IP to a specific MAC.

Comment: I've got DD-WRT, I just wanted to avoid having to log into it every time I want to look up an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a label maker to affix the IP address to each computer?  Or, you could write it on a piece of tape with a Sharpie, if you're feeling more primitive.

Comment: Well, I'd like to be able to look up the information on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Many times you can set up a DHCP server to act as a DNS server as well. which means that you could put the name you are using to refer to a specific machine into the address bar, or use `dig` to find the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angry Ip Scanner](http://www.angryziber.com/w/Home) to automatically scan a local subnet.  It can generate a CSV or XML with:

- computer name
- IP address
- MAC address
- workgroup/domain

etc.